# SELECT WHERE over multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, mariadb

I have three tables as follows

Table recipe

```
id | name
1  | Pasta
2  | Whatever
```

Table ingredient

```
id | name
1  | Spaghetti
2  | Tomato sauce
```

Table recipe_ingredients

```
id | recipe_id (FK recipe.id) | ingredient_id (FK ingredient.id)
1  | 1 (Pasta)                | 1 (Spaghetti)
2  | 1 (Pasta)                | 2 (Tomato sauce)
```

I want to `SELECT` a recipe based on a list of ingredients, like "find recipe with ingredient 1 AND 2"

How would I achieve that?

**edit from comments below:**

Just to add to my original question: I was able to get an EXACT match by doing a

```
SELECT ... WHERE GROUP_CONCAT... = '1,2'
```

but that will give me only the exact recipe with ingredients 1 and 2, not recipes which might have ingredients 1,2 and 3 - which is what I actually want.

Comment: This is a very basic sql. Get some sql knowledge by doing some tutorial. Good place to start will be: .https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: Genius advice, thank you. Just to add to my original question: I was able to get an EXACT match by doing a SELECT ... WHERE GROUP_CONCAT = '1,2', but that will give me only the exact recipe with ingredients 1 and 2, not recipes which might have ingredients 1,2 and 3 - which is what I actually want.

Comment: Can we download a copy of these recipes. They seem about my level.

Comment: @Decay42 this kind of advices (even more when they are upvoted) might really be worthy to consider. If you want to add something to your question, edit it, so ppl don't have to read the comments to see it

Comment: Too trivial for an 'answer': `SELECT r.* FROM recipe r JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON ri.recipe_id = r.id WHERE ri.ingredient_id IN (1,2) GROUP BY r.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ri.ingredient_id) = 2;` Note that the id column on your ri table is redundant (unless, I suppose, where an ingredient is used for both the main body of the meal, and for the garnish, say)

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it works:

```
select *
from  recipe_ingredients r1
where 1=1
and exists (select 1 from recipe_ingredients r2 where ingredient_id = 1 and r1.recipe_id = r2.recipe_id)
and exists (select 1 from recipe_ingredients r3 where ingredient_id = 2 and r1.recipe_id = r3.recipe_id) -- rinse and repeat these lines
```

Comment: Agreed, on both counts.

Comment: @Strawberry Oh you're just full of sass today, aren't you? XDDDDD

Answer (score 0):

SELECT recipe_id
       FROM ingredients
       WHERE ingredient_id IN (1,2)
       GROUP BY recipe_id
       HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

This technique has the feature of finding recipes that include at least 3 of several ingredients:

```
   WHERE ingredient_id IN (11,22,33,44,55)
   GROUP BY recipe_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
SELECT ri.*, i.*, r.* FROM recipe_ingredients ri, recipe r, ingredient i
WHERE ri.ingredient_id = i.id AND ri.recipe_id = r.id AND
ri.ingredient_id in (1,2)
```

Comment: OP Wants recipes with ingredients 1 AND 2, not 1 OR 2, which is what you're doing I think